# How can I resolve the following dimension mismatch with R's K nearest neighbors?

Tags: r

In the code below, I am trying to use K nearest neighbors with a single predictor. 
To the best of my understanding, there's no need for the number of examples in `train.X` to match the number of examples in `test.X`, but `R` seems to not be parsing my input correctly.

```
library(ISLR)
library(class)

train=(Weekly$Year<2009)
train.X = Weekly$Lag2[train]
test.X = Weekly$Lag2[!train]
train.Direction = Weekly$Direction[train]
knn.pred = knn(train.X, test.X, train.Direction, k=1)
```

When the code above is run, it gets the error

```
   Error in knn(train.X, test.X, train.Direction, k = 1) :   
      dims of 'test' and 'train' differ
```

How can I fix `train.X` and `test.X` so that `R` parses them correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `knn` function takes matrices or data frames as arguments for train and test set. You're passing in a vector, which gets interpreted as a matrix, but not in the way you want. Specifically, the data you pass in is interpreted as a single data point with the different values denoting the features. This means that the number of features for train and test is different, as the error message suggests.

To fix, simply convert explicitly, e.g.

```
knn.pred = knn(data.frame(train.X), data.frame(test.X), train.Direction, k=1)
```

Comment: This solution works, but is that the only way to force R to interpret the vector in the way that I want?
In particular, I tried transposing the vectors that but just results in a length mismatch error message.

Comment: You can also convert it explicitly to a matrix with appropriate dimensions.

Comment: What's the syntax for that?

Comment: `matrix(train.X, ncol=1)`

Answer (score 3):

This is because R automatically tries to coerce to the least number of dimensions when subsetting a matrix, array, or data frame. To prevent dropping the dimension of dataframe you can use the subset function which defaults to `drop=FALSE`.

```
train.X <- subset(Weekly[train],select="Lag2")
```

You can also use a logical expression as a parameter to indicate rows or elements to keep:

```
train.X <- subset(Weekly,Year<2009,select="Lag2")
```

subset function also keeps the column names intact letting you use `train.X$Lag2` as a valid column. Using data.frame or as.data.frame as suggested in another answer will miss original name information.

```
> names(train.X)
[1] "Lag2"
```